# Accordion jQuery через класс модификатор .active

Tags: jquery

Как написать аккордион на jQuery на основе чередования классов active?

https://jsfiddle.net/75pxcjny/

Написал, но я так понимаю, что он вообще не рабочий у меня.

```
$('.accordion-content .accordion-title').click(function () {
  var target = $(this).attr('data-accordion');
  $('.accordion-content > .accordion-title').removeClass('active');
  $('.accordion-content > .accordion-title').addClass('active');
  $('.accordion-content .accordion-body').removeClass('active');
  $('.accordion-content .accordion-body' + target).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btnAccordion = $(".accordion-title");

btnAccordion.on("click", function() {
  $(".accordion-title.active").removeClass("active").siblings(".accordion-body").slideUp();
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".accordion-body").slideDown();
})
```

```css
.accordion-container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.accordion-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 100%;
}

.accordion-title.active {
  color: red;
}

.accordion-content:first-child .accordion-body {
  display: block;
}

.accordion-body {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
}

.accordion-body:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.accordion-container .accordion-content .accordion-body p {
  line-height: 170%; // bull shit
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <button type="button" data-accordion="#content1" class="accordion-title active">#1   Вопрос №1?</button>
    <div class="accordion-body" id="#content1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, delectus earum minima laborum vero qui molestiae in exercitationem maxime sunt.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, magnam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <button type="button" data-accordion="#content2" class="accordion-title">#1   Вопрос №1?</button>
    <div class="accordion-body" id="#content2">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, delectus earum minima laborum vero qui molestiae in exercitationem maxime sunt.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, magnam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <button type="button" data-accordion="#content3" class="accordion-title">#1   Вопрос №1?</button>
    <div class="accordion-body" id="#content3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis, delectus earum minima laborum vero qui molestiae in exercitationem maxime sunt.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, magnam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну например так. У вас слишком большая вложенность CSS так не надо. + Вы не правильно используете элемент ссылка. Ссылка используется Только если надо переправить на другую страницу.